# Why does the Java PriorityQueue implementation use Comparator<? super E> and not simply Comparator<E>

Tags: java, generics, java-8, priority-queue

The Java PriorityQueue source code defined in jdk8 uses a comparator defined like this

```
    /**
     * The comparator, or null if priority queue uses elements'
     * natural ordering.
     */
    private final Comparator<? super E> comparator;
```

Source code [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java) (line 108)

Why the need for using a type that is super of E and not simply E.

In other words, why not define the comparator just like below:

```
    private final Comparator<E> comparator;
```

What is the motivation behind that extra abstraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because why not.

Given a comparator that can compare any 2 CharSequence objects (CharSequence is an interface; String, StringBuilder, and a few other things implement it), then.. that is just as good when you have a need to compare only strings. All Strings are also CharSequences, so a comparator that can tell you for any 2 charsequence objects which one 'comes first' can do the job perfectly well.

Generics are invariant by default, so if you have a `PriorityQueue<String>`, and it worked like you want to, it'd look like `Comparator<E>`, which means `Comparator<String>`, and a `Comparator<CharSequence>` is **not compatible** with that. Like passing a `String` to a method that wants an `Integer` object, it just doesn't compile.

Hence, `<? super E>` so that you *can* pass a `Comparator<CharSequence>`.

It doesn't come up often, of course, but it's 'more correct' this way. I'm sure you'd be surprised if you so happen to have a comparator of CharSequences laying about and can't use it to power a `PriorityQueue<String>`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it makes sense!
For the why not, I would only say there is a bit more cognitive overhead when reading code that has ? super E rather than simply E. Though I agree that it's still worth it, because of the benefits you mentioned.